# How can I use OrientDB with Django?

Tags: python, django, orientdb, non-relational-database

I am building a Django project that uses a relational DB (for development purposes SQLite) and an non-relational DB (OrientDB). This is my first time a using non-relational DB and I m having difficulty getting it set up with Django.

The use of OrientDB in my project is solely to keep track of friend relationships and friend-of-friend relationships, while all other user data is being stored in my relational DB.

I know I need to register the DB in my settings file. I am trying to do something like this:

```
#setting.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },

    'friends': {
        'NAME': 'friends',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.orientdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'hello',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '2480',
    }
}
```

When I do this, however, I get the error:

> No module named 'django.db.backends.orientdb'

Is this backend module something I have to create myself or can I manually connect to the DB in my code whenever I need something specific done?  For example, whenever someone creates a new user in my SQLite DB, can I use a Signal `post_save` to

1. connect to OrientDb,
2. create a friend instance in Orient DB, and
3. disconnects from OrientDB?

It seems like there ought to be a much cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly something you'll need to build yourself, though your use case doesn't sound like it requires a whole Django backend. A few manual queries might be enough.

Django [officially supports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/) PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, and Oracle. There are [third-party](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend) backends for SAP SQL Anywhere, IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, Firebird, and ODBC.

There is an [abandoned project](https://github.com/tomtalp/Djangorient) that attempted to provide an OrientDB backend for Django, but it hasn't been updated in quite a long time and likely needs a lot of love:

> This project isn't maintained anymore, feel free to fork and keep it alive.

No matter how you choose to proceed you should probably take a look at [OrientDB's Python library](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/PyOrient.html).